# Local user account disabled date

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

Any way to get the disabled date of local user account. I am good with Active Directory user accounts. But not able to get with local user account disabled date

Comment: You can get that from the event logs on the DC!

Comment: Someother approach other than eventlogs will be great for me!!